# How to validate a date in Xquery

Tags: validation, date, xquery

If I have a date in YYYYMMDD format how to validate in Xquery version "1.0",  so that it checks for month and year are valid and if say they are valid then a leap year with month as 02 can have a date 29 else a max 28.

Several integration tools such as Oracle Fusion Middleware implement Xquery version "1.0" not "3.0"

Comment: I hope you don't intend to flood the xquery tag with more question like your recent ones. A very quick search would have given you this: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_mmddyyyy-to-date.html

Comment: I dont think that replied my question there is no validation i guess...As it says: The functx:mmddyyyy-to-date function converts $dateString into a valid xs:date value. I dont need to convert a invalid date to valid date I need it to return boolean, so as to use in a if condition.

Comment: The difference is non-significant and to change this behavior is trivial. You seem to lack a required minimal understanding of XQuery and I would recommend to read a few tutorials/books/whatever you like first.

Comment: he man i know i am not a Xquery-Xpath guru thats why i ask questions but still i have knowledge to say the link u mentioned is just converting date in dd * mm * yyyy where * represents any separator into format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: And if you would have tested it yourself you would have noticed that if it is an invalid date (like 02/29/2010) it throws an error, otherwise it does not. Now its up to you to figure out how to catch the error and simply translate this to `true()`/`false()`

Comment: I don't expect you to be a guru, but I do expect you to do some basic research yourself and test for yourself. We are not here to provide all the code for you.

Comment: Ya i got it now @dirkk will try to do research first Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, although your use case is rather simple: generally avoid tampering with dates (and especially times) on your own, and always rely on already implemented functionality, [handling date and time is *horribly* complicated if you want to do it right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result).

Convert the string to a representation that XQuery's date functions are able to parse. If you can construct a date from the string, it is valid; if an error occurs, it is invalid. Dates can be constructed using `xs:date($string)`. One way to convert the string would be using using `substring(...)` and `string-join(...)`:

```
  xs:date(string-join((substring($date, 1, 4), substring($date, 5, 2), substring($date, 7, 2)), '-'))
```

To catch an error, use a [`try`/`catch` block](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-try-catch).

Comment: Xquery version "1.0" does not supports try/catch block and worse OSB implementation doesn't even support castable as